# Taskpane is not working in Latest build OfficeJS Excel

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

Post updating Excel into latest version, our deployed application not working as expected.

1. For prior version which is attached here, sample hosted application was working fine with taskpane,
2. Once it is updated with latest excel build #, taskpane is not working properly like if clicking any of very first ribbon command then taskpane is getting displayed after which it is not displayed other commands clicks.

**Prior Verson**

[image]

**Latest Version**

[image]

**Below Error Screen:**

[image]

Comment: is your add-in published in store? if yes, would you please share the name?
meanwhile, can you try to install another add-in, and see if it work in your machine?

Comment: No Raymond.....it is in-house sample deployment like uploading manifest in Office Admin Center and getting manifest through ADMINMANAGED tab in Excel... Also I have attached error screen shot...